# на JS удалить часть html-кода (блок и все вложенные теги со всем содержимым)

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, как на `JS` убрать из исходного кода страницы конкретные блоки, которые не имеют нужного класса?

Не по клику, а при обычной загрузке страницы

например:

```
< div class="block><br/>
  < div class="visible">.....< /div> оставить в исходном коде
  < div>...с вложенными тегами...< /div> убрать из исходного кода
  < div>...с вложенными тегами...< /div> убрать из исходного кода
< /div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без стрелочных функций:

```html
<div class="block">
  <br>
  <div class="visible">.....</div>
  <div>...с вложенными тегами...</div>
  <div>...с вложенными тегами...</div>
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
    
    blocks.forEach(function (block) {
      var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(block.children);
      
      children.forEach(function (child) {
        if (!child.classList.contains('visible')) {
          block.removeChild(child);
        }
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

А зачем js? Почему бы просто не спрятать при помощи css?

```html
<style>
  .block > * {
    display: none;
  }
  .block > .visible {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<div class="block">
  <br>
  <div class="visible">.....</div>
  <div>...с вложенными тегами...</div>
  <div>...с вложенными тегами...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: через ctrl-U как-бы убранные блоки остаются в исходном коде страницы  http://joxi.ru/nAyX1eEugj3aG2 
можно как-то убирать эти блоки до формирования структуры страницы?

Comment: Думаю нет. Ctrl+U, как я понимаю, показывает текст который пришёл в ответ на ссылку. Причём показывает не запуская JavaScript. Единственный способ настолько спрятать элементы страницы, это не рисовать их на стороне сервера.

Comment: жаль. нашел способы через remove() и detach() удалять. через инспектор смотришь - удалились, а через ctrl-U проверяешь исходный код страницы - все на старых местах без изменений.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded', ev => document
    .querySelectorAll ('.block :not(.visible)')
    .forEach (el => el.parentNode.removeChild (el)))
```